# ¿Como evitar que el personaje salte en el aire con Raycast 2D?

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Estoy realizando un juego *2D en Unity*, modifiqué el código para que el personaje no se deslizara cuando hubiese pendientes en el escenario y la única forma en la que lo encontré fue con **Raycast**, sin embargo, ahora no detecta cuando el personaje se encuentra en el suelo por lo que puede realizar el salto incluso en el aire indefinidamente.

Ya intenté utilizar Raycast para modificar el salto pero el personaje sigue consiguiendo saltar en el aire, incluso la animación de salto y caída no la hace.

A continuación les dejo el player controller en el que estoy trabajando:

```
public Transform groundCheck;
public Transform rayCastOrigin;
public LayerMask groundLayer;
public float groundCheckRadious;

private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
private Animator _animator;
private RaycastHit2D _isGrounded;
//Esta es la variable que utilizaba originalmente
//private bool _isGrounded;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    void Grounded()
    {
        //Esta es la instrucción que tenía originalmente
        //_isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadious, groundLayer);
        //Esta es la instrucción nueva que utiliza Raycast
        _isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(rayCastOrigin.position, -Vector2.up, 100f, groundLayer);
        if (_isGrounded != false)
        {
            Vector2 temp = groundCheck.position;
            temp.y = _isGrounded.point.y;
            groundCheck.position = temp;
        }
    }
    
    void Jump()
    {
        //Is Jumping?
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _isGrounded == true && _isRolling == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Salto");
            _rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el error se produce en el Raycast, el output del Raycast es un bool. Si hay suelo debajo, independientemente de la distancia, siempre será true, porque está comprobando si el Raycast colisiona (true) o no (false).

Las posibles soluciones podrían ser:

- Comprobar la distancia hasta el suelo: si es menor que una predeterminada haz que si que toque el suelo, algo así

```
float _minDist; // Distancia mínima para considerarse tocando suelo
RaycastHit _hit;
bool _enSuelo;

    if (_hit.distance < _minDist) // Si la distancia de el choque es menor que la mínima:
    {
        _enSuelo = true;
    }
        else
    {
        _enSuelo = false;
    }
```

- Comprobar la colisión con un collider del suelo:

```
bool _enSuelo;

OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "suelo")
    {
        _enSuelo = true;
    }
}
```